# one point sets are open as a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be our set and let the topology $\tau$ be given by the smallest topology such that the intersection of two lines is open.

So I take this to mean singletons are open so for any $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\{\vec{x}\} \in \tau$.

So the first question I have is that, do we still have for any $\epsilon>0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ that $B_\epsilon(x) \in \tau$? (i.e., is it standard TOGETHER with one point sets being open or?)

Then I need to tell if $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$ is 1st countable? And 2nd countable?

Does the first one mean having countable basis at each point? And the second one just says we have a countable basis?

Any hints would help.

Comment: If singletons are open, any set (union of singletons) is open; that's the [discrete topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702951/why-are-singletons-open-in-a-discrete-topology)

Comment: ah that right so then every subset ends up in the topology??? since $\tau$ closed under arbitrary union of open.

Comment: First countable is trivial, can you see why? It is not second countable because we have an injection between any collection of disjoint open sets and any basis. As $$\{\{x\} \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ is an uncountable collection of disjoint open sets, any basis is also uncountable.

Comment: I see that, but for some reason do not see why it is first countable because as you mentioned the class of singletons is uncountable so how can I construct a countable basis at each point? Or

Comment: wait do I take each singleton and it is its own countable open set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it implies that all sets $\{x\}$, where $x \in \Bbb R^2$, is open in $\tau$.

But recall that all unions of opens sets are open too, so if $A \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ is any subset, $A = \bigcup\{\{x\}\mid x \in A\}$ is also open in $\tau$ so that $\tau$ is the powerset of $\Bbb R^2$; the topology is discrete.

So $\Bbb R^2$ is first countable trivially, every point $x$ has a local base $\{\{x\}\}$, which is finite, so countable.

For every base for $\tau$ we must have $\{x\}$ in the base for any $X$, so no countable base exists for $\tau$ and the space is not second countable.